# what is the best for remembering users? cookies or database or both?

Tags: php, security, cookies, web

I saw many open source websites, its uses different methods for remembering their logged in users, some of it uses just cookies and some uses cookies and database.
What is the diffidence between each method? and what is the best method to use?

I think there is a security reasons, can any one help me to understand ?

Comment: Neither a cookie nor a database alone is sufficient. A cookie stores a session ID, but the server needs _some_ way (gasp! a database of some variety) to tie that session ID to a session object.

Comment: Even if it's legit in your country please don't spy on your users. Using cookies will give them an option wether they want the benefits you offer by recognizing them or rather like not to be tracked at all.

Comment: @mikyra Spying on users? What are you talking about?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk: something like violating  Directive 95/46/EC (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_Directive) as an example.

Comment: what i want to understand is that i can just use cookies for remembering users by storing information about them help me to identify users, why i need to use the database?

Answer (score 1):

All "remember me" functions will require a cookie or some other way to leave a bit of information on the users computer so that you can identify him/her later. You would then take this bit of information that will help you identify the user on your server, and do, whatever you have to do to log him/her back into your system.

Answer (score 1):

To remember a user, across their visits, you HAVE TO use cookies. A DB cannot do it.

Session variables last only for a session. e.g. if you use session variable then you would not 'remember' the users the next day.

You need to DB to store information about the users in a permanent fashion. You do not need it per se for 'remember me' function. If e.g. all you need to know about the user is their name, might as well store it in cookie itself. When the user comes back, the name is there in the cookie and can be uses to say 'Welcome foo'. if however e.g. the page is e.g. an email client, then you cannot be possibly be storing all users emails in a cookie; not that it would make sense anyways. In this scenario you would get the login credentials from the cookie, mark the user logged in, and then dip into the DB to fetch their emails.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are faster because they are stored locally on the user's computer.

A database requires that you make a connection on a server to fetch the data.

You should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious) for a more comprehensive guide.

Comment: See my comment on the question. This answer is misleading and overly simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies doesn't update at the time otherwise Sessions does, so I think the best way for remembering users is by Session ids, and a database

Comment: Cookies can be updated as frequently as you want them to be. If you're talking about the expiration of the cookie, then yes.